# Solving the recurrence relation T(n) = n*T(n - 1) + n! (n > 0, T(0) = 2)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Can someone solve the recurrence relation mentioned above and asymptotic time complexity using back substitution? I know the master's theorem way to solve it, but I don't know how to obtain that answer using back substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand:

```
T(n) = n*((n-1)*T(n-2) + (n-1)!) + n! =
       n*(n-1)*T(n-2) + n! + n!       =
       n*(n-1)*T(n-2) + 2 * n!        =
       n*(n-1)*((n-2)*T(n-3) + (n-2)!) + 2n! = 
       n*(n-1)*(n-2)*T(n-3) + 3 * n!
```

By induction, you can prove:

```
T(n) = n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 3 * T(2) + (n-2) * n!
```

As we know `T(0) = 2` and `T(2) = 2 T(1) + 2! = 2 * (T(0) + 1) + 2 = 8`:

```
T(n) = 4 * n! + (n-2) * n! = (n+2) * n! = (n+1)! + n! = \Theta((n+1)!)
```

Comment: So what is the asymptotic time complexity or Big O notation?

Comment: but Master's theorem would give the answer as O(n^2n)

Comment: @ChinmayVemuri How do you use the Master theorem here? What is `a` and `b` in the master theorem?

Comment: I guess a = n and b = 1

Comment: @ChinmayVemuri you are wrong! `a` and `b` should be constant! Also, you can't write `n-1` in the form of `n/b`!